# Angular5 [routerLink]="['/url']" Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: diff, routerlink, angular5

```
<a [routerLink]="['/url']" class="weui-cell__ft text-d">title</a>
```

Angular5 `[routeLink]="['/url']"` throw a `Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`.

```
ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (vendor.js?v=zEe6VsaL2DL3c66V6dkahN0BFDflNeSabH3Fz48ci10:18645)
at NgForOf.ngDoCheck (vendor.js?v=zEe6VsaL2DL3c66V6dkahN0BFDflNeSabH3Fz48ci10:35895)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (vendor.js?v=zEe6VsaL2DL3c66V6dkahN0BFDflNeSabH3Fz48ci10:23401)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (vendor.js?v=zEe6VsaL2DL3c66V6dkahN0BFDflNeSabH3Fz48ci10:24901)
at checkAndUpdateNode (vendor.js?v=zEe6VsaL2DL3c66V6dkahN0BFDflNeSabH3Fz48ci10:24844)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (vendor.js?v=zEe6VsaL2DL3c66V6dkahN0BFDflNeSabH3Fz48ci10:25716)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (vendor.js?v=zEe6VsaL2DL3c66V6dkahN0BFDflNeSabH3Fz48ci10:25657)
at Object.View_HomeComponent_0.__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__.ɵvid._co [as updateDirectives] (home.component.html:78)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (vendor.js?v=zEe6VsaL2DL3c66V6dkahN0BFDflNeSabH3Fz48ci10:25642)
at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.js?v=zEe6VsaL2DL3c66V6dkahN0BFDflNeSabH3Fz48ci10:24811)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a routerLink="/url"  class="weui-cell__ft text-d">title</a>
```

And you will have to define your "url" route into your route.config also. For more info : https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: if you this found the solution as helpful then please up-vote and mark it as answered.